# How to read file with sections using ajax .post()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a text file, "abc.txt" that I want to read with a jQuery .post() call.  The file has three sections: section1, section2, and section3. I'd like to do something clever in jQuery that lets me pull out section1, section2, and section3 text separately. My first thought was to modify the file to mark out the sections with xml-type brackets, like

```
<section1>The section 1 text</section1>
<section2>The section 2 text</section2>
<section3>The section 3 text</section3>
```

Then the post() call could be something like

```
fileName = "abc.txt"

$.post('loadPage.php', {fileName : fileName},function(xml) {
        var sect1= $(xml).find("section1");
    },
    "xml");  // dataType
```

But this fails on a couple of levels.  First the "xml" datatype at the end seems to keep the post() from working.  I guess my little xml-like tags didn't fool ajax into thinking it was xml data. Second, if I leave out the dataType I get stuff back, but the $(xml).find("section1"); blows up.

Am I anywhere close to having something that works here?

loadPage.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$siteName       = $_POST['siteName'];
$fileName = "{$siteName}_sav.html";
$fileSize = filesize($fileName);
$filePath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $fileName;
echo ("<br /> reading $fileSize bytes from $filePath");
$site_fp = fopen( $filePath, 'r');
$xml = fread($site_fp, $fileSize);
if($xml) {
    echo ("<br />xml: " . htmlspecialchars($xml));
}
else {
    echo ("<br />Read from $fileName failed");
}
```

?>

It's actually an html file, not a txt file, if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: What does loadPage.php look like? Does it just do a file_get_contents() on $_POST['fileName']?

Comment: what does loadPage look like? Are you opposed to off-loading most of the functionality into your php codE?

Comment: I modified the question to show loadPage. I'd consider off-loading functionality to the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Start with proper XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> // or whatever
<section1>The section 1 text</section1>
<section2>The section 2 text</section2>
<section2>The section 3 text</section3>
```

and as those are root elements, you should be using `filter()` not `find()` but the best option is probably to append the xml to another element so it works either way :

```
fileName = "abc.txt"

$.post('loadPage.php', {fileName : fileName}, function(xml) {
    var sect1 = $('<div />').append(xml).find("section1");
}, "xml");
```